# Spring Kafka: applying KafkaListenerErrorHandler to all KafkaListener

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, error-handling, spring-kafka

I want to intercept validation errors (MethodArgumentNotValidException) throwing by my @KafkaListener's. To achieve that i created DefaultKafkaValidationErrorHandler which implements KafkaListenerErrorHandler:

```
@Component
public class DefaultKafkaValidationErrorHandler implements KafkaListenerErrorHandler {


    @Override
    public Object handleError(Message<?> message, ListenerExecutionFailedException exception, Consumer<?, ?> consumer) {
       //here is some logic
    }

    @Override
    public final Object handleError(Message<?> message, ListenerExecutionFailedException exception) {
        //such as here
    }
}
```

And set a validator to the registrar:

```
@Component
public class KafkaListenerConfig implements KafkaListenerConfigurer {
    @Autowired
    private LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator;

    @Override
    public void configureKafkaListeners(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistrar registrar) {
        registrar.setValidator(this.validator);
    }

}
```

It works fine while i putting this handler to my listener directly

```
@KafkaListener(
            containerFactory = "factory",
            topics = "topic",
            groupId = "group.id",
            errorHandler = "defaultKafkaValidationErrorHandler")
```

My question is, is there some way to apply my DefaultKafkaValidationErrorHandler to all @KafkaListener in my project, and not directly as mentioned. Maybe through ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory, KafkaListenerEndpointRegistrar or something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override a `C createListenerContainer(KafkaListenerEndpoint endpoint);` method of the `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory` and set your global `KafkaListenerErrorHandler` into everything single `endpoint`. Your factory must be registered under the `KafkaListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.DEFAULT_KAFKA_LISTENER_CONTAINER_FACTORY_BEAN_NAME` bean name to avoid configuring this factory on every single `@KafkaListener`.